# Flask HTTP Basicauth - How does it work?

Tags: python, authentication, flask, basic-authentication

I'm trying to create a login system using Flask and HTTP Basic Auth. My question is, is it my responsibility to provide user information from databases, or does  basicauth create and access those databases for me? If it doesn't, what can I use to do that?

Comment: basicauth is a standard for exchanging usernames and passwords with a server.. It won't provide user information to authenticate against, no.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Werkzeug can decode the Basic Authorization header for you, into the username and password. The rest is up to you to see what you want to do with that information.

The [`request.authorization` attribute](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.AuthorizationMixin.authorization) returns a [`Authorization` object](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.Authorization). For basic authentication headers, only `username` and `password` are set.

A project like [`Flask-Login`](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) can help you manage more complex logins with Basic Authorization, and tie that in with a user model you provide. That model can be stored in a database or anything else you so desire.

And you can look at [Flask-Security](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/) for a more fully integrated security package that uses Flask-Login and other packages to provide Basic Authentication and session based logins.

Answer (score 20):

The [Flask-HTTPAuth](http://flask-httpauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) extension (shameless plug, I'm the author) simplifies the implementation of HTTP Basic Auth. Instead of working with the `request.authorization` data directly you set up callback functions where you plug the authentication logic.

Regarding your database question, Flask-HTTPAuth makes no assumptions about how your users are stored. You have to provide the logic that retrieves users and validates passwords.

Comment: Thanks, very good extension. There are also some good examples on the main page. https://flask-httpauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Does it work with `gunicorn`?

Comment: @mirekphd Yes, of course.

Comment: This question might be of interest too: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74688222/9962007 ;)

Answer (score 18):

Werkzeug parses the `Authorization` header into `request.authorization`, which is an [`Authorization`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.Authorization) object.

For security reasons, a browser might only send this header if it first received a 401 error response with a `WWW-Authenticate` header set. A different client, such as the requests library, will send the header directly.

The simplest demonstration of this is a decorator that checks `request.authorization` and returns a 401 response if it's not set, or if the credentials were invalid. In practice, you should use an extension such as [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/) or [Flask-HTTPAuth](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flask-httpauth) to manage this.

```
from functools import wraps
from flask import request

def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapped_view(**kwargs):
        auth = request.authorization
        if not (auth and check_auth(auth.username, auth.password)):
            return ('Unauthorized', 401, {
                'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="Login Required"'
            })

        return f(**kwargs)

    return wrapped_view

@app.route('/secret')
@login_required
def secret():
    return f'Logged in as {request.authorization.username}.'
```

```py
import requests
response = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/secret', auth=('world', 'hello'))
print(response.text)
# Logged in as world.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Flask Basic authentication example using Python decorator function.

It will return 401, Authentication required if not auth or wrong auth.

### Flask API

```py
def check_auth(username, password):
    return username == 'username' and password == 'password'

def login_required(f):
    """ basic auth for api """
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        auth = request.authorization
        if not auth or not check_auth(auth.username, auth.password):
            return jsonify({'message': 'Authentication required'}), 401
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function

@app.route('/', methods=["GET"])
@login_required
def home():
    return {"Hello": "world"}
```

### While requesting on server

```py
response = requests.get(url, auth=('username', 'password'))
```