# userinfo component in Flask URL

Tags: python, url, flask, rfc3986

I would like for my users to connect to my Flask app using a syntax such as:

```
http://username:password@myapp.com/
```

as defined by RFC 3986 (chapter 3.2).

Is there a way I can access the `username:password` part from Flask?

On my local server, if I access `http://username@localhost:5000/` from Chrome for instance, I don't see anything in Flask's `request` object, and the `username@` part disappears from the address bar immediately.

xoxo

---

EDIT on May 1st:

This question has been marked as a duplicate of [Flask HTTP Basicauth - How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22919182/flask-http-basicauth-how-does-it-work)

However, my question is not related to the basic auth protocol. `request.authorization` is `None` in my case.

---

Second EDIT:

OK, my bad, it turns out the `username:password@host` does implement the basic auth protocol but this syntax has been deprecated and is not implemented anymore by some browsers, including Chrome (see the bottom of [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication))