# 405 Method not Allow, methods=["POST", "GET"] not working

Tags: python, post, flask, http-status-code-405

I am learning from a flask tutorial online, and I am watching videos on POST and GET. One of the exercises is to run a simple form submission returning the username on a new @app.route(). I tried adding A password and username to try to simulate a login because I thought I was cool but failed. The code is below.

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)


realUser: str = "name"
realPass: str = "pass"


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("extension.html")


@app.route("/login", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.form["un"]
        password = request.form["password"]
        if realUser == user and password == realPass:
            return redirect(url_for("user", usr=user))
    else:
        return render_template("extension.html")


@app.route("/<usr>")
def user(usr):
    return f"<h1>{usr}</h1>"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

extension.html:

```
{% extends "ThePurpleLounge.html" %}
{% block title %}Home Page{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Login</h1>
<form method="post">
    <p>Name:</p>
    <p><input type="text" name="un" /></p>

    <p>Password:</p>
    <p><input type="text" name="password" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="submit" /></p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

ThePurpleLounge.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

I even tried simplifying my code to:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("extension.html")


@app.route("/login", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.form["un"]
        return redirect(url_for("user", usr=user))
    else:
        return render_template("extension.html")


@app.route("/<usr>")
def user(usr):
    return f"<h1>{usr}</h1>"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

However, it still says 405 Method Not Allowed. The tutorial went straight into the code so maybe I have to install or configure something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `@app.route("/")` you are not allowing POST method. So when you are trying to send a form with the url http://127.0.0.1:5000/ the server rejects it.
But if you correct that there is another problem: You implemented the login method at another url (`@app.route("/login", methods=["POST", "GET"])`).

Here is a working modification of your code (`/` redirects to `/login` )

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)


realUser: str = "name"
realPass: str = "pass"


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return redirect(url_for("login"))


@app.route("/login", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.form["un"]
        password = request.form["password"]
        if realUser == user and password == realPass:
            return redirect(url_for("user", usr=user))
    else:
        return render_template("extension.html")


@app.route("/<usr>")
def user(usr):
    return f"<h1>{usr}</h1>"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This kind of code is interesting to understand how flask works. To go a bit further with authentication methods, you should have a look at [Flask HTTP Basicauth - How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22919182/flask-http-basicauth-how-does-it-work) .

Comment: OH WOW THANK U IT WORKS, and I will have a look at the Flask HTTP Basicauth.