# Flask-HTTPAuth: how to pass an extra argument to a function decorated with @auth.verify_password?

Tags: python, authentication, flask, basic-authentication

Here's a small Flask app authenticated with `Flask-HTTPAuth`.

How to pass an argument (such as authentication on/off flag, or verbosity level / debug on/off flag) to a function (such as `authenticate` below) decorated with `@auth.verify_password` (without raising an error)?

Current code:

```py
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()

authorized_users_dict = [..]

# [..]

@auth.verify_password
def authenticate(username, password):    

    if username in authorized_users_dict:
        
        if check_password_hash(pwhash=authorized_users_dict[username], password=password):
            return True

    # [..]

# [..]

@auth.login_required()

# [..]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think passing this dictionary as an argument is the best choice. I assume this dictionary is fixed, so there is actually no technical reason to pass it as an argument every single time there is an incoming request.

But, if you feel strongly about it, one way to do it is with the `partial` function from the Python standard library. Something like this:

```py
from functools import partial

authorized_users_dict = [..]

def authenticate(users_dict, username, password):    
    if username in users_dict:
        # ...

auth.login_required(partial(authenticate, authorized_users_dict))
```

Comment: OK, point taken, I will likely skip the dict as argument. But another use case turned out to be more valid: passing verbosity level to `authenticate` that will print/log (or not - in PRD) the time taken to compare password with the hash (which turns out to have a significant impact on overall API performance depending on the number of iterations used in the hash - default 250k iterations in `generate_password_hash()` led to timeouts:).

Comment: Oh, and you probably solved another problem at once: switching off Basic Auth for backward API compatibility (e.g. passing `USE_BASIC_AUTH` flag to `authenticate`). So you have also effectively provided one of the simplest answers to the many "conditional decorator?" questions on SO.

Comment: The logging verbosity is often set on the logger object. It is also inefficient to pass a logging verbosity setting to every function that logs, don't you think? In general I see that you are always preferring to pass arguments into functions for things that are (or should be) configuration. Using global variables, or better, the `app.config` dictionary is a better way to handle these static values that don't need to be passed as arguments every time because they never or rarely change.

Comment: Yes, and I use global variables (here also decided to pass values via global vars `FLASK_VERBOSE` and `USE_BASIC_AUTH` to `authenticate`), config dicts, lists, and other objects (pre-loaded at app startup) and some config class instances (and indeed a custom Logger classs). But decorators are really a special case, effectively backward jumps (e.g. here back to the `authenticate` (which itself cannot be declared upfront or in an external module since it receives all sorts of arguments via environment...) from the `@auth.login_required` decorator)

Comment: I don't understand why the decorator is a concern. You will be accessing these configuration options in the decorated function, not in the decorator itself. The decorated function should have access to `current_app.config`, where it can obtain any configuration values.